# values are not inserting to SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I created one app for testing with `two edittexts` (`Email` and `password`) and 2 buttons (`submit` and `viewdata`). I was debug this application and it is working fine.

I wanted to update this application by adding one more `Edittext` (`Name`) and upgrade the `SQLite Database` in `onUpgrade()` method. The code is shown below.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="upgrade";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;

//details table details
public static final String TABLE_NAME_Details="details";
public static final String USERNAME="USERNAME";
public static final String PASSWORD="PASSWORD";
public static final String Name="Name"; //newly added column in version 2


public static final String TABLE_NAME_Details_temp="temp";
public static final String USERNAME_temp="USERNAME";
public static final String PASSWORD_temp="PASSWORD";
public static final String Name_temp="Name";

//create table statements for version 2
public static final String Create_Table_Details = "CREATE TABLE "
+ TABLE_NAME_Details + " (" + USERNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
+ PASSWORD + " TEXT ,"
+ Name + " TEXT"
+")";

/*   creation for version 1
private static final String Create_Table_Details = "CREATE TABLE " + 
TABLE_NAME_Details + "("
+ USERNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
+ PASSWORD + " TEXT"
+ ")";*/
//Alter table statements FOR onUpgrade()
//private static final String ALTER_Details = "ALTER TABLE " + 
TABLE_NAME_Details + " ADD COLUMN" + Name + " TEXT";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
try{
db.execSQL(Create_Table_Details);
Log.d("database","installed successfully");
}catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("/test","Exception due to"+e.toString());
}
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{

String TEMP_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + 
TABLE_NAME_Details_temp + "("
+ USERNAME_temp + " TEXT," + PASSWORD_temp + " TEXT )";
db.execSQL(TEMP_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_Details_temp + " SELECT " +  
USERNAME + ", "
+  PASSWORD + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME_Details);

db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME_Details);

String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Details + "("
+ USERNAME + " TEXT," + PASSWORD + " TEXT," + Name + " TEXT )";
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_Details + " SELECT " +  
USERNAME_temp + ", "
+  PASSWORD_temp + ", " +  Name_temp + ", " + null + " FROM " + 
TABLE_NAME_Details_temp);
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Details);
}

public boolean insertData(String username, String password,String name)
{
try{
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(USERNAME,username);
contentValues.put(PASSWORD,password);
contentValues.put(Name,name);
long result=db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME_Details, null, contentValues);
if(result==-1)
return false;
else
return true;
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("/test","Exception due to"+e.toString());
return false;
}
}
//update value
public boolean updatePassword(String LoggedUsername)
{
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
try {
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(PASSWORD, "test");
if (db.isOpen()) {
db.update(TABLE_NAME_Details, values, USERNAME + "='" + 
LoggedUsername+"'",null);
return true;
}
else
return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("eEmp/DBUpdateUser ", e.toString());
return false;
}
}
//getting data from database
public Cursor getAllData()
{
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME_Details,null);
return res;
}
}
```

I installed the 1st version and working fine and then uninstalled.

After uninstallation, installed the 2nd version and it stores the data. it is also working fine.

When I am trying to update the 1st version with the 2nd version in debug mode, the app updated successfully and the data that entered in the 1st version is visible. and when I am trying to store the data in 2nd version, the data is not inserting to sqlite database. Why?

While debugging, insert method is called but here `if(result==-1)` I am getting -1 instead of 1. so, data control comes out from the method and the data is not inserting to database.

For example: In 1st version: I entered username: `stackoverflow` and password `stackoverflow`.
and I updated the app to 2nd version and updated successfully. Now I entered username: `hello`  password:`hello`  name:`hello` and then click on submit button.

After that If I click on `viewdata` button: it display  username: `stackoverflow` password `stackoverflow` name:null. But not displaying the data inserted in 2nd version.

Any help would be appreciated. Please help me with the correct solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
      // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        String TEMP_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TEMP_TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(TEMP_CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

        // Create an temporaty table that can store data of older version

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TEMP_TABLE_CONTACTS + " SELECT " +  KEY_ID + ", "
                +  KEY_NAME + ", " +  KEY_ADDRESS + " FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

// Insert data into temporary table from existing older version database (that doesn't contains ADDRESS2 //column)

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+ TABLE_CONTACTS);
// Remove older version database table

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

// Create new table with ADDRESS2 column
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " SELECT " +  KEY_ID + ", "
                +  KEY_NAME + ", " +  KEY_ADDRESS + ", " + null + " FROM " + TEMP_TABLE_CONTACTS);
// Insert data ffrom temporary table that doesn't have ADDRESS2 column so left it that column name as null.     
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TEMP_TABLE_CONTACTS);
    }
```

Comment: where should I keep these 2 lines in onUpgrade method?@vikas singh

Comment: yes.. because when you upgrade your db version then you should drop your old table and recreate.

Comment: If I drop the table, then how to retrieve the details from old table?

Comment: Can you explain me what it does?db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD COLUMN New_Column_Name INTEGER DEFAULT 0");@vikas singh

Comment: and here my column datatype is TEXT

Comment: @bhavana check my edited code it's working fine with me. I hope it's helpful for you

Comment: db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " SELECT " +  KEY_ID + ", "
                +  KEY_NAME + ", " +  KEY_ADDRESS + ", " + null + " FROM " + TEMP_TABLE_CONTACTS); while executing this getting exception.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO details SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, Name, null FROM temp

Comment: Write your query like this, pass null where u have the extra column INSERT INTO details SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, null FROM temp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161587/discussion-between-bhavana-and-vikas-singh).

Answer (score 1):

there is a typing mistake check it you column name is db is

```
public static final String Name="Name"; //newly added column in version 2
```

and you are using `NAME_` change it while inserting data in sqlite

Try this

```
try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(USERNAME,username);
    contentValues.put(PASSWORD,password);
    contentValues.put(Name,name);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME_Details, null, contentValues);
    if(result==-1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("/test","Exception due to"+e.toString());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: but still getting the exception.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table details has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO details(USERNAME,PASSWORD,Name) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: uninstalled and installed again. but same exception is coming @Guruji. please help me

Comment: I observe one issue. if I dont enter any data in version 1, after updating app onUpgrade method is calling and alter statement executed and data is inserting. If I enter values in version1, then after updation, onUpgrade method is calling data collected from previous version after that exception came.@Guruji

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't catch exceptions in `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()`. If there's a problem, the method must not return normally. Returning normally means everything was successful and the database schema is ready to use.
2. Notice the missing whitespace in your `onUpgrade()` `ALTER TABLE`:

   ```
   private static final String ALTER_Details = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Details + " ADD COLUMN" + NAME_ + " TEXT";
   ```

   between `COLUMN` and `NAME_`. This causes the upgraded database to not work. Fresh install only goes thru `onCreate()` and the bug in `onUpgrade()` is not exposed.
3. Use `insertOrThrow()` instead of `insert()` to get more helpful error messages, such as "no such column".

Comment: I changerd the alter query.  
I observe one issue. if I dont enter any data in version 1, after updating app onUpgrade method is calling and alter statement executed and data is inserting. If I enter values in version1, then after updation, onUpgrade method is calling data collected from previous version after that exception came.

Comment: Is there any problem with alter query?@laalto